# Small program to visualize the content of an iCalendar .ics file

Tags: calendar, offline, desktop-client

I am looking for a small program that can import an [iCalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) file and shows its content in a graphical "calendar" way.

Context: my company scheduling software can export .ics (iCalendar) files, and I want to be able to vizualise its content **offline**. Of course, I can alway import it into Google calendar or similar app, but I wan't to be able to do this off-line, without the hassles of web-apps.
Just something like:

```
>someapp my_ical_file.ics
```

And this will generate some output, either through some GUI window, or (even better) generate an image or an html page showing the calendar view.

The idea is to be able to visually compare such files, in an easier way than what would done with [`diff`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility).

The best would be free software, or at least a Linux version available.

I know about the [Lightning](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/projects/calendar/) add-on to [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/), but I am looking for an independent solution, not integrated into something huge like Thunderbird (and whose core business is email, not calendar).

Answer (score 2):

Since you want something more independent than Lightening, how about its predecessor, [Mozilla Sunbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Sunbird). It's a standalone offline calendar manager. It was discontinued when Mozilla started focusing on Lightening, but you can still get the old versions on common download websites. It is cross-platform, and it has a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/sunbird_portable) so you can run it directly from a USB drive.

It is compatible with iCalendar files ([Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_applications_with_iCalendar_support) is a comprehensive list of software that are)

Comment: Well, of course, I couldn't miss Sunbird. But not only it has been discontinued by Mozilla, but it seems that the whole project vanished: I wasn't able to locate any source repository anywhere !!! All the Mozilla page about Sunbird now point to Lightning. And some download sites still have it, but only the Windows version (AFAIK). So that doesn't help me much. If you do happen to know a location for source, I'd be interested. Anyway, thanks for the link on the Wikipedia page, I did miss that one, I'll check there if I find anything.

Comment: You're right. Most links either lead to Lightening or are Windows installers. I found [this one](http://sunbird.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu) which downloads a .deb file. I hope it works.